# How to prove that a proposition that contains only $\iff$ is a tautology iff it has an even number of members $p$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

A proposition $φ$ consists of only $\iff$ as links. Show that $φ$ is always true iff every member $p$ (each $p$ takes either 0 or 1 as values) has an even number of showings in $φ$

At first i thought i thought that, since $\iff$ is true only when both members have the same value (true or false), then a double showing can always be true if we rearrange the parentheses?

But even if that is the case, i have no idea how i can begin to prove it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $(a \iff b) = a \oplus b \oplus 1$. As $\oplus$ is associative and commutative, order and grouping of variables in $\phi$ doesn't matter - the only thing that affects it's value is number each variable appears, and total number of $\iff$.

Formally, by induction on length of $\phi$, we can show that if $X$ is set of variables that appear odd number in $\phi$ then $\phi \leftrightarrow \bigoplus_{x \in X} x \oplus 1^{|\phi|}$ (where $1^n$ if $1$ if $n$ is odd and $0$ if $n$ is even and $|\phi|$ is number of $\iff$ in $\phi$).

If $X$ is non-empty then $\phi$ is non-constant, thus not always true.

If $X$ is empty, then every variable has an even number of appearances, so total number of variables (with multiplicity) is even. And as number of $\iff$ is one less then number of variables, $|\phi|$ is odd in this case, so $\phi \leftrightarrow 1^{|\phi|} = 1$.

Comment: This is a better answer than the two answers to the question that this one duplicates.